# How to check if you are on widget.php page?

Tags: plugins, widgets

I am trying to write a widget and I need to add the color picker to my widget form. I want to add the script only on widget.php page and not on all the admin pages.

Is there a way that I can detect the page inside the construct function of my widget? If not how I can include the script only when I'm on widget.php page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the global variable [`$pagenow`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals) to figure out if you are on a particular **admin page**, in your case this would be checking if you are on the `widgets.php` admin page:

```
<?php 

    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow === 'widgets.php' ) {
        ?>
        <script>

            // JavaScript goes here

        </script>
        <?php 
    }
```

Furthermore, it will be helpful for you to use the plugin [Query Monitor](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) so that you may easily find out what conditionals may be used on a particular instance.

Comment: Or just `$GLOBALS['pagenow']`, which has the benefit of fitting into one line, no need to declare the global access on a separate line.